# How to "hide" a textField and then bring it back?

Tags: textbox, lua, coronasdk

I have a program with multiple tabs, so when I go to a new tab I want to somehow temporarily get rid of all of the elements on the other tabs until the user returns to that certain tab.  I am having trouble doing this with textFields, once I hide them I cannot get them to reappear.  So far I have tried removeSelf, delete, and isVisible and all of them have had the same problem.  Is there another way to temporarily hide a textField and bring it back later on?

edit: this is in Lua using the Corona SDK

Comment: What code are you using? What engine? Which API?

Answer (score 0):

You can normally do it with isVisible or with the .alpha property :)
Set .alpha = 0 when you change tab, and .alpha = 1 when you come back to the tab.